# Why Autofac type resolution does not work in Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I saw similar issues in the web but my situation is that on localhost my WebAPi app works fine but fails in Azure where it complains that the type `PositionServer.Repository.PositionRepository,PositionServer.Repository` could not be found. It may require assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly"

Here is autofac.json

```
{
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "PositionServer.Repository.PositionRepository,PositionServer.Repository",
            "services": "PositionServer.Interfaces.IPositionRepository,PositionServer.Interfaces",
            "autoActivate": true,
            "instanceScope": "per-dependency"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an issue with Autofac but how the Azure publish works. It is not enough to copy the dependent dlls to the bin folder of the web api project using a post build action. It must be referred as well so I suppose the publish looks at the .csproj file / nuget pkg to do the deployment. The Azure site works after referring to the project of the PositionRepository assembly